# cannot return unique elements from matches

Tags: javascript

I want to return _1, _2 and not _1, _2, _1 :

```js
let regex = /_[0-9]/g;
let string = 'a_1 b_2 c_1';
let matches = [...string.matchAll(regex)];
let unique = [...new Set(matches)];
alert(unique);
```

can't see why it doesn't remove duplicates ?

Comment: flatten the matches array? `[...string.matchAll(regex)].flat()`

Comment: @evolutionxbox great it works though why is it nested ?

Comment: `matchAll` returns an array of matches, which are each an array themselves

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks will look further !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a different method, `matchAll` might not be the best here, flatten the matches array before passing to the Set constructor:

```js
let regex = /_[0-9]/g;
let string = 'a_1 b_2 c_1';
let matches = [...string.matchAll(regex)].flat();
let unique = [...new Set(matches)];

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using `.matchAll`, which will return an iterator that, when turned into an array, results in:

```
[
  ['_1', index: 1, input: 'a_1 b_2 c_1', groups: undefined],
  ['_2', index: 5, input: 'a_1 b_2 c_1', groups: undefined],
  ['_1', index: 9, input: 'a_1 b_2 c_1', groups: undefined]
]
```

So, deduplicating the array items with a Set doesn't work - arrays are never === to each other.

Use `.match` instead of `.matchAll` so you get an array of matches (strings), not an array of arrays.

```js
const regex = /_[0-9]/g;
const string = 'a_1 b_2 c_1';
const matches = string.match(regex);
const uniqueMatches = [...new Set(matches)];
console.log(uniqueMatches);
```

Comment: thanks but I had existing code written by others with matchAll